# Defining a Template in Flex

Tags: compilation, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis, lexical

I want to define a "KEYER" in flex, which is a "KEY" in "[]". A "KEY" is starting with a letter and a string of letters, numbers and the following characters: "~_'?$. -".
I defind:

```
keyChar         ([a-zA-z0-9~_'?$. \-])
letter          ([a-zA-Z])
key             ({letter}{keyChar}+)
keyer           ("["{key}"]")
```

and:

```
<*>{keyer}        print("KEYER");
```

Somehow the input:

```
[keyer1] [keyer2] [keyer 3]
```

is read as one KEYER and not three of them. what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `A-z` instead of `A-Z` in the pattern for `keyChar`. `[A-z]` includes the characters between `Z` and `a`, which include brackets.

On the whole, it is better to avoid range expressions when not necessary. I would have written:

```
keyChar         ([[:alnum:]~_'?$. -])
key             ([[:alpha:]]{keyChar}+)
keyer           ("["{key}"]")
```